# Changing Location of Velocity.Log File

Tags: apache, velocity, logfiles

Seems pretty straight forward. Documentation at http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Logging
says to set the runtime.log property. Here's what I got for all my properties.

```
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, templatesPath);

            velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log", "/path/to/my/file/velocity.log");
            velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "string");
            velocityEngine.setProperty("string.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader");
            velocityEngine.setProperty("string.resource.loader.repository.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.util.StringResourceRepositoryImpl");
```

Not finding any log file where I told it to place it and instead finding the new errors placed into old (folder of initialization) location. Any ideas? :D

Comment: That looks right to me.  Does the location have the right permissions?  as an alternate, you can also use log4j and have this merged in your regular application log.

Comment: did you make changes as per below answer and got this converted in velocity.properties?

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem when setting at runtime some options.  I figured out those problem whit a custom VelocityBuilder and an external velocity.properties file where you can put all the runtime properties.
Here is the code:

```
public class BaseVelocityBuilder implements VelocityBuilder {
    private VelocityEngine engine;

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    public VelocityEngine engine() {
        if(engine == null) {
            engine = new VelocityEngine();

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = webApplicationContext.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/velocity.properties");
                properties.load(in);
                engine.init(properties);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("Error loading velocity engine properties");
                throw new ProgramException("Cannot load velocity engine properties");
            }

            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }

        return engine;
    }
}
```

See this line:

```
            in = webApplicationContext.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/velocity.properties");
            properties.load(in);
            engine.init(properties);
```

So i have a velocity.properties file in /WEB-INF where i put some configuration:

```
    resource.loader = webinf, class

webinf.resource.loader.description = Framework Templates Resource Loader
webinf.resource.loader.class = applica.framework.library.velocity.WEBINFResourceLoader

webapp.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.WebappLoader
webapp.resource.loader.path =

file.resource.loader.description = Velocity File Resource Loader
file.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
file.resource.loader.path =

class.resource.loader.description = Velocity Classpath Resource Loader
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
runtime.log='/pathYouWant/velocity.log'
```

In the end in your application.xml :

```
    <bean class="applica.framework.library.velocity.BaseVelocityBuilder" />
```

In this way you can have for example different file log for different application and when you give the war in production, the sysadm can change the properties due to env configuration of the production server.