# Change the Location of Velocity.Log File

Tags: jboss, velocity, permission-denied

I used velocity-1.6.2.jar

my problem that **velocity.log** is created on the server start under **jboss/bin**

**jboss/bin** has read only permission.

and in my appilcation  when velocity-1.6.2.jar will be called I have this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: velocity.log (Permission denied)
```

I want to change the location of Velocity.Log File

This is the location line in my **velocity properties**:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  default LogChute to use: default: AvalonLogChute, Log4JLogChute, CommonsLogLogChute, ServletLogChute, JdkLogChute
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.ServletLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.JdkLogChute

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is the location of the Velocity Runtime log.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

runtime.log = velocity.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Location of Velocity.Log File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221354/changing-location-of-velocity-log-file)

Comment: how to make it refer from velocity.properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Runtime log](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.6/developer-guide.html#simpleexampleofacustomlogger) can get full path so just direct log to your desrirable folder as /home/velocity.log

```
 runtime.log = /home/velocity.log
```

> Full path and name of log file for error, warning, and informational messages. The location, if not absolute, is relative to the 'current directory'.

### Update (27-02-2018)

The log path can also be set programmatically as following:

```
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
public class VelocityCustomEngine extends TemplateEngine {

    private final VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

    public VelocityCustomEngine() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("runtime.log", "/home/velocity.log");

        this.velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine(properties);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to make this in velocity.properties ?

Comment: velocity.properties is not getting picked up, i wanted to know what changes are there in web xml and in which location you put velocity.properties

Answer (score 2):

I know there's an answer. In case you don't want to extend the original VelocityEngine.
You can also new a VelocityEngine instance only changed the "runtime.log" properties before the init() method without any new class.

```
        VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
        velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log", "/home/velocity.log");
        velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.ENCODING_DEFAULT, "UTF-8");
        velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        velocityEngine.init();//init method will use the properties(include the log file location) actually.
        return velocityEngine;
```

Comment: how to make this code refer from velocity.properties ?